# Table of values of nDeriv(f(x),x,x) vs. f'(x) gives different results??

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\cos(e^x)$$

So, I work out that:
$$f'(x)=-\sin(e^x)(e^x)=-e^x\sin(e^x)$$

For fun and amusement, I wanted to verify this is the actual derivative, 
So, using a Ti84+, I tried to enter both of these functions and compare the table of values.

But, when I do 2nd-->table, I get diverging values once x>5

Any idea what's going on?  I tried adding ()'s to ensure proper order of operations.
Is this a glitch in the internal algorithm for estimating derivatives?

Thanks!

Comment: which are the 2 functions?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem here. If you plot $\cos e^x$ you will see that the oscillations become more and more rapid, so that the slope increases without bound. That is consistent with $f'(x)$ getting arbitrarily large.

Comment: I may not have been clear.  The subject title.  I graphed $y=-e^xsin(e^x)$ and $y=nDeriv(cos(e^x),X,X)$     When I looked at the table of values, I saw different numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values of $x$ greater than about $2$, these functions start looking pretty wild. When the TI84+ does `nDeriv` it is calculating the slope of the secant line through two points on the graph:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{f(x+\varepsilon) - f(x -\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon}
$$
Specific to this problem, the default value of $\varepsilon$ that the calculator uses is $10^{-3}$. Considering how wildly $\cos(e^x)$ starts to oscillate, with this value of $\varepsilon$ the calculator will start giving false derivative values.

The function `nDerive` does take an optional fourth argument of a specific value of $\varepsilon$ if you want to try to change it and get more accurate results, but for the function $\cos(e^x)$ it doesn't look good.

Also, just as a general note, since the TI84+ does use the secant method to find the numerical derivative, it will return a value even if the function is non-differentiable at that point.

**Edit:** After running a few tests, letting $\varepsilon = 10^{-8}$ keeps `nDeriv` of $\cos(e^x)$ and its actual derivative of $-e^x\sin(e^x)$ in agreement up to $x=17$.

```
seq(nDeriv(cos(e^X), X, A, 1E-8), A, 1, 20) -> L1
seq(-(e^X)(sin(e^X)), X, 1, 20) -> L2
```

Comment: Ok, so the nDeriv estimation algorithm has error b/c the function is oscillatting so wildly?

Comment: Can you review how the TI84+ estimates a derivative?  It calc's the secant slope with some threshhold $\varepsilon$?   So, it will repeatedly calculate the f'(x) formula you listed above for each point?  At x=1 it will use values at f(.999) and f(1.001) ?

Comment: Right, so when the TI84+ calculates $f'(x)$ at $x=1$ using `nDerive`, it will find the slope of the line between the two points $(.999, f(.999))$ and $(1.001, f(1.001))$. This is using the threshold $\varepsilon = 10^{-3}$. If we were to use $\varepsilon = 10^{-8}$ like I did above and punch in `nDeriv(f(x), x, 1, 1E-8)`, it would find the slope of the line between the two points $(.99999999, f(.99999999))$ and $(1.00000001, f(1.00000001))$.